# Why is my character not jumping in godot (2D)

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

According to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mc13Z2gboEk, so far, at 1:02:44, my character is supposed to be jumping, but on my screen it isn't.

Here is the code I have for the Player script:

```
extends Actor

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    var direction: = get_direction()
    velocity = calculate_move_velocity(velocity, direction, speed)
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, FLOOR_NORMAL)
    
func get_direction() -> Vector2:
    return Vector2(
        Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left"), 
        -1.0 if Input.is_action_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor() else 0.0
        )

func calculate_move_velocity(
        linear_velocity: Vector2,
        speed: Vector2,
        direction: Vector2
    ) -> Vector2:
    var new_velocity: = linear_velocity
    new_velocity.x = speed.x * direction.x
    new_velocity.y += gravity * get_physics_process_delta_time()
    if direction.y == -1.0:
        new_velocity.y = speed.y * direction.y
    return new_velocity
```

Here is the code for the Actor script:

```
extends KinematicBody2D
class_name Actor
    
const FLOOR_NORMAL: = Vector2.UP

var velocity: = Vector2.ZERO
export var speed: = Vector2(300.0, 1000.0)
export var gravity: = 4000.0
```

I have put in the correct input maps, double checked it, un-added and re-added, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `calculate_move_velocity`, you have the arguments in this order:

- `velocity`.
- `direction`.
- `speed`.

Here:

```
    velocity = calculate_move_velocity(velocity, direction, speed)
```

But your declaration of `calculate_move_velocity` has the parameters in this order:

- `linear_velocity`.
- `speed`.
- `direction`.

Here:

```
func calculate_move_velocity(
        linear_velocity: Vector2,
        speed: Vector2,
        direction: Vector2
    ) -> Vector2:
```

So you are passing:

- `velocity` into `linear_velocity`.
- `direction` into `speed`.
- `speed` into `direction`.

If that sounds correct to you, I don't know what to tell you.

*I see this issue with a fresh mind, not arriving from dealing with the code. You probably just needed a good rest and you would have seen it.*

Comment: Hey, thanks for clarifying, turns out you were right, I completely missed it, thanks a lot! appreciate it!!